# (f o g) o f composition function

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

If $f$ represents the function $f(x)$ and $g$ represents the functions $g(x)$, is $(f \circ g)\circ f$ essentially $f(g(f(x)))$?

I know that:

> $(f \circ g) = f(g(x))$

however I'm not sure if the brackets in my equations make a difference to this new function.

Comment: short answer: yes!

Comment: Function composition [is associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523906/show-that-function-compositions-are-associative), so $\,(f \circ g) \circ f = f \circ (g \circ f) = f \circ g \circ f\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets make no difference: the composition of functions is completely associative, meaning that $(f\circ g)\circ h=f\circ(g\circ h)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Furthermore, $(f \circ g) \circ f  = f \circ g \circ f = f \circ (g \circ f)$ by associativity.